# Using different colors on patterns for ggplot box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(3)
values <- rnorm(36)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
mydat <- data.frame(time = factor(c(rep(0, 12), rep(1, 12), rep(2, 12))),
                    class = factor(rep(c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6)), 3)),
                    method = factor(rep(c(rep("Manual", 3), rep("Automatic", 3)), 6)),
                    value = values)
> head(mydat)
  time class    method       value
1    0     A    Manual -0.96193342
2    0     A    Manual -0.29252572
3    0     A    Manual  0.25878822
4    0     A Automatic -1.15213189
5    0     A Automatic  0.19578283
6    0     A Automatic  0.03012394
```

I have a data set with 4 categories: 2 classes x 2 methods. I want to make a side-by-side box plot at each time point with different colors and patterns.

```
> ggplot(mydat, aes(x = time, y = value, fill = method, pattern = class)) +
  geom_boxplot_pattern(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), aes(pattern = class, pattern_fill = class), pattern_density = 0.35) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))
```

This gives me the following, where the patterns are not aligned correctly:

[image]

I would like it to look something like this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single layer. You can specify one of the patterns as "none" and one as "stripe" via `scale_pattern_manual`

```r
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = time, y = value, fill = method, pattern = class)) +
  geom_boxplot_pattern(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
                       aes(pattern = class), pattern_fill = "black",
                       pattern_density = 0.05, pattern_angle = 45,
                       pattern_spacing = 0.03, width = 0.6) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c("none", "stripe")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = 'none'))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#fddaf0", "#dfffda")) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to remove the pattern in colored boxplots under the 'method' legend? i.e., just have a pink and a green boxplot without the pattern in the legend